# How to hide superfish menu from login page in drupal 7

Tags: menu, drupal-7, superfish

I have configured the superfish block to display on all pages EXCEPT the user-login page but this is not being honored. I've also created a superfish menu block with no menu items and have configured to ONLY show on the user-login page but this is not being honored.

Why am I trying to do this? There are 3 dummy menu items (not associated with pages) which I cannot make 'disappear' via context rule e.g. only show when user == authorized user (see screen capture).

So if someone knows how to hide the dummy menu items or the whole superfish block from the login screen - please share - it would be appreciated.

[Login Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQScL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just checked it on one of my sites ... it should work when you add "user" in the display section of the block config page. (you may have to clear the cache)... But than, the block is also hidden on all user pages for autorized users..
Other options: "hook preprocess_page" or just a seperate page template ("page--user.tpl.php")...